# Proper Ansible syntax for passing variable to Jinja2 template file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to reference a variable in jinja2 template file:

```
"args": ["{{ consul_healthcheck }}"]
```

How can I write the variable value so I can achieve:

```
"args": ["curl", "localhost:8500"]
```

I tried something like this:

```
consul_healthcheck: ["curl", "localhost:{{ consul_port }}"]
```

And it resulted in:

```
"args": ["[u'curl', u'localhost:8500']"]
```

Any links to explaining the proper syntax for this would be appreciated. I was not able to locate what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the template looks flawed to me from an engineering point of view (it clearly was intended to be a single element list), you can still trick Jinja2 to produce your wanted result by passing a string (without opening and closing quote character):

```
vars:
  consul_port: 8500
  consul_healthcheck: curl", "localhost:{{ consul_port }}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was wondering if there is a quick way to test these type of syntax? I was testing part of long playbook which I was only trying to fix the syntax part.